# How to break a signal chain in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

By editing a manual text field in the QML, a sequence of signals is called: **textEdited()** and then **textChanged()**. I have two handlers one for **onTextEdited** the other for **onTextChanged**.

How do I block the **textChanged()** call in the **TextEdited()** handler?
How do I interrupt a signal call sequence?

```
TextField {
    id: _field
    background: _textBackground

    onTextChanged: {
        _textBackground.border.color = "#FFBDBDBD"
        _textBackground.border.width = 1
    }

    onTextEdited: {
        _textBackground.border.color = "#FFE57439"
        _textBackground.border.width = 2
    }
}

Rectangle {
    id: _textBackground
    border {
        width: 1
        color: "#FFBDBDBD"
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this code? I don't understand what is the actual goal.

Comment: @GrecKo The code in the `TextField` field can be changed programmatically and manually. When programmatically changes, the `TextChanged()` signal is triggered, when manually the `TextEdited()` signal is triggered first, and then the `TextChanged()` signal automatically. So I don't want the `TextChanged()` signal to fire after the `TextEdited()` signal. The program code has been simplified for a better understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by introducing the **isEdit** flag into the code.

```
TextField {
    id: _field
    property bool isEdit: false
    background: _textBackground

    onTextChanged: {
        if (!isEdit)
        {
            _textBackground.border.color = "#FFBDBDBD";
            _textBackground.border.width = 1;
        }
        isEdit = false;
    }

    onTextEdited: {
        isEdit = true;
        _textBackground.border.color = "#FFE57439";
        _textBackground.border.width = 2;
    }
}

Rectangle {
    id: _textBackground
    border {
        width: 1
        color: "#FFBDBDBD"
    }
}
```

After the **onTextEdited** signal handler is executed, the **onTextChanged** handler is executed, but it contains a check if the **onTextEdited** handler was previously executed. If the handler has been executed, the body of the conditional statement is skipped.

Answer (score 2):

You should not try to prevent signals from being emitted. Rather you should try to find an elegant way to achieve what you want to.

---

From what I understood you have two requirements:

1. *Execute some code when the text is edited manually*

   The signal [`onTextEdited`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#textEdited-signal) is emitted whenever the text is changed **manually**. Therefore it's a perfect fit for your requirement
2. *Execute some code when the text is edited programmatically*

   The signal `onTextChanged` is **always** emitted when the text changes. Therefore it's not usable for this requirement.

   You could e.g. use a function to change the text programmatically and execute the additional code.

---

In the end your code could look something like this:

```
TextField {
    id: _field
    background: _textBackground

    onTextEdited: {
        _textBackground.border.color = "#FFE57439"
        _textBackground.border.width = 2
    }

    // Call this function whenever the 'text' property should be changed programmatically
    function changeTextProgrammatically(newText) {
        text = newText
        
        _textBackground.border.color = "#FFBDBDBD"
        _textBackground.border.width = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!